# Warning route-recognizer

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I need some help here..

Just updated my ember-cli to 0.1.9 version and the only problem is this warning:

> Warning: ignoring input sourcemap for
>   bower_components/route-recognizer/dist/route-recognizer.js because
>   ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   '/Users/Zaca/Eyenetra/portal/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-kOIywY0K.tmp/bower_components/route-recognizer/dist/route-recognizer.js.map'

Here's my call to this addon on brocfile.js:

```
//brocfile.js
(...)
app.import('bower_components/moment/moment.js');

app.import({development: 'bower_components/route-recognizer/dist/route-recognizer.js'});
app.import({development: 'bower_components/FakeXMLHttpRequest/fake_xml_http_request.js'});
app.import({development: 'bower_components/pretender/pretender.js'});

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

This happens when I build my project for tests and for local server.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help! o/

Comment: I'm using CLI v0.1.8 and pretender and getting the same error. I'm brand new to pretender and might be doing something wrong. Out of interest, is Pretender behaving correctly for you?

Comment: So, after some cleanup, it worked. I'll update the post with the cleanup steps.

Comment: thanks, very interested. I have pretender working albeit the throttling feature doesn't seem to work and I still get the above error.

Comment: It's great that you found an answer to your own question. I moved your self-answer to the answers section. It's faster for readers in the future if you keep them isolated.

Comment: make sure the appropriate bower packages are installed (if you're using them) or removed from `Brocfile.js` or your addon's `index.js` (in this latter case you're likely not using that addon either so just remove the addon).

Answer (score 1):

We have actually moved away from using Pretender, since at the moment we always have a staged API up and running.

In doing that, we removed the following from our Brocfile:

```
app.import({development: 'bower_components/route-recognizer/dist/route-recognizer.js'});
app.import({development: 'bower_components/FakeXMLHttpRequest/fake_xml_http_request.js'});
app.import({development: 'bower_components/pretender/pretender.js'});
```

With that the warning went away.

Aside: I'm unsure of the implications of not having route-recognizer there, but so far there has been no effect without it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still getting this problem, even after deleting my component and tmp folders and cleaning my caches.  However, looks like this is a known issue that a lot of other people are having as well:

https://github.com/tildeio/route-recognizer/issues/44

I will be watching this to see when an update comes out.  In the meantime I guess I will just have to live with the warning.

There is already a temporary fix here:

https://github.com/tildeio/route-recognizer/pull/45/files

Answer (score 0):

After some cleanup, this warning message never happened again.

To really cleanup, you have to do these steps:

```
rm -rf bower_components/
rm -rf dist
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -rf tmp

npm cache clean
bower cache clean
```

And, after, the normal install steps

```
npm install
bower install
```

Hope that work for analog situations =)

Answer (score 0):

I found that doing an ember install of some dependencies worked.
We had mirage and yadda dependencies. I did

```
ember install ember-cli-mirage
ember install ember-cli-yadda
```

and then

```
ember build

Built project successfully. Stored in "dist/"
```

You do some great things with ember and then there are days like this.